# Modular Arithmatic

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have been struggling with modular arithmetic, and I would like to try and finally grasp the concept.
In particular, solving problems like $7^{30}$ mod 49.

I know I will have to use Fermat's Theorem and from it we will have $7^{31-1}=1$ mod 31

But from here I am stuck.

Thanks for the  help!

Comment: I'm confused. How are you using Fermat's Theorem. For one, $30 \neq 29-1$, perhaps you meant $31-1=30$ and $31$ is prime. Are you trying to find $70^30 \mod 49$ or $\mod 29$?

Comment: I am trying to find $7^{30}$ mod 49.  I thought that Fermat's theorem said to make it $7^{29-1}$ but I clearly did not see that correctly.  So it would be $7^{31-1}$ mod 31 ?

Comment: @user108949 Fermat's Little Theorem only works with a prime $p$ using $\mod p$. Notice that None of $48,49,50$ are prime. So this won't work. You'll have to do this using normal modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate $7^{30} \mod 49$, then the easy way to do this would be to observe that $7^2=49$, so that 
$$
7^{30}=(7^2)^{15}=(49)^{15}\equiv 0 \mod 49
$$
So $7^{30}$ is divisible by $49$.

Comment: Great, that makes sense.  Thanks!
However, what if it was mod 31 and we could not use the fact hat $7^2 = 49$?

Comment: @user108949 If you wanted to use $\mod 31$, well $31$ is prime and $30=31-1$ so we can use Fermat's Little Theorem which says $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p$, if $p$ doesn't divide $a$. Well, $31$ certainly doesn't divide $7$. And as I pointed out, $30=31-1$ and $31$ is prime. All the conditions have been met, so $7^{31}\equiv 1 \mod 31$. Meaning $7^{31}$ is 'almost' divisible by $31$.

Answer (score 1):

Working modulo $\;49\;$ :

$$7^2=0\;,\;\;7^{30}=(7^2)^{15}=\ldots$$